# JAVA Variable Scope

Tags: java

I am looking through some old questions for a test and I come across a quite easy question however it wasn't what I expected.

```
public class Exampractice {
  public static void f(int x, int[] y, int[] z) {
    x = 2;
    y[0] = x;
    z = new int[5];
    z[0] = 555;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 111;
    int[] y = {222, 333, 444, 555};
    int[] z = {666, 777, 888, 999};
    f(x, y, z);
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y[0]);
    System.out.println(z[0]);
  }
}
```

The question asks what is the result of the following code. 
I get the following results:

```
111 
2 
666
```

I understand why x is 111 as local variables override all other variables, y[0] =2 as the code says it equals x which is 2 but I am lost on why z[0] = 666 as it has been rearranged in the f class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: It is fairly easy to understand if you remember few things:  
1) in Java all variables are passed by value - i.e. you get a copy of the primitive data types and a copy of the reference to a complex data type. 2) `new` operator creates completely new object, it does **not** update the existing object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, the object reference is passed as a value. Therefore, when `z = new int[5];` is executed, the local array variable `z` present in the `f()` method now refers to the newly created `int` array and nothing happens to the original array whose reference was passed as a value to it when the method was called.

```
public static void f(int x, int[] y, int[] z) {
    x = 2;
    y[0] = x;
    // Till here z is referring to the int array passed from main method
    z = new int[5]; // now z is re-assigned with a new reference, the one of the newly created int array
    // thus the reference to the original array is no more being used here
    z[0] = 555; // this modifies the values of the newly created array 
}
```

Personally, I always suggest reading [this answer by Eng.Fouad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/2024761) to understand this concept.

Comment: I see how it works now... Took a little while to get my head around it

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `new` which creates new object

Answer (score 1):

What matters is whether the value or reference is set to variable

x has value

```
    x=111
```

and

```
    y and z
    points two different arrays
```

y and z are not having value it has a reference of an array

```
    reference y[0] is edited globally  in f

    z is recreated in the method f locally using "new"
```

It does not affect original object in method main() so we get that result.

Answer (score 0):

The method creates a new int array. The old one is intact after the method exits.

Answer (score 0):

Z is a new object, the z in the function is actually this.z